# Adding additional routes to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

I have a `comments` controller:

```
  match 'comments/count' => 'comments#count'
  resources :comments
```

I'm trying to map mysite.com/comments/count to a newly defined `count` action within the `comment` controller. What I have above doesn't seem to work. I get the following error:

> Unknown action
>
> The action 'show' could not be found for CommentsController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

even though i think that this should work, there are better ways to do this. have a look at the `member` and `collection` attributes of resources:

```
resources :photos do
  member do
    get 'preview'
  end
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

in your case i think this would be

```
resources :comments do
  get 'count', :on => :collection
end
```

Comment: +1 for using the correct `member` and `collection` routes (as opposed to static `match` routes)!